# Im trying to get key input to work by getting and setting x/y values but it isnt working

Tags: java

I know that the the image is drawing constantly but the x/y coordinates arent changing which doesnt let the image move.. Why is this happening and what can i do to fix it

```
import java.awt.*;


public class GameState extends State {

  private Player player;
  private int playerX = 1440/2 - 14, playerY = 810/2 - 14;

  public GameState(SuperHexagonGame game)
  {
    super(game);
    player = new Player(playerX, playerY);
  }



  public void tick()
  {
    player.tick();
  }

  public Player getPlayer()
  {
    return player;
  }

  public void render(Graphics g)
  {
    g.drawImage(Assets.bg1, 0, 0, null);
    player.render(g);
  }
}
```

player class

```
import java.awt.*;


public class Player extends Creature {

  public Player(int x, int y)
  {
    super(x, y);
  }

  public void tick()
  {
  }

  public int getX()
  {
    return x;
  }
  public int getY()
  {
    return y;
  }
  public void setX(int x)
  {
    this.x = x;
  }
  public void setY(int y)
  {
    this.y = y;
  }

  public void render(Graphics g)
  {
    System.out.println(y);
    g.drawImage(Assets.player1, x, y, null);
  }

}
```

key input class that checks for key input. Im trying to get it to set the xy values in the player class by getting the current xy value and adding/subtracting 75

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter {
  private Player player = new Player(1440 / 2 - 14, 810/2 - 14);
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
 {
   int key = e.getKeyCode();
   System.out.println(key);

   if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
   {
     //decrement y by 75
     player.setY(player.getY() - 75);
   }
   if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
   {
     //increment y by 75
   }
   if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
   {
     //decrement x by 75
   }   
   if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
   {
     //increment x by 75
   }
 }
}
```

i know the program is getting keyboard input (arrow keys) because when pressing a key it displays the keycode into console it but it isn't setting the xy values to the new xy values for movement. I only have the code done for up arrow key because I wanted to make sure it worked before copy pasting.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `Player`s here. `Player player = new Player(1440 / 2 - 14, 810/2 - 14);` and `player = new Player(playerX, playerY);`.

I would say, you are editing one player and printing the other one. Try adding the following:

```
public class KeyInput extends KeyAdapter {
    private Player player;
    public KeyInput (Player player){
        this.player = player;    
    }
}
```

Comment: should i use a getter to get the `player` from the `GameState` and replace the other `player`?

Comment: I editted my answer. Just create 1 player, and pass it to the `KeyAdapter`, this way, you will be editing the player your created.

Comment: Thank you, i got it to work now! :) do i have to like mark this question as solved?

Comment: yea so i dont waste anyone else's time